# What is the PCH chipset model for HP Pavilion 17-ab004nc?

Tags: motherboard, chipset, hp

My Platform Controller Hub (PCH) blew up and I am looking for replacement. Does anyone know how can I choose a proper replacement for the chipset?

Comment: According to [your HP Product specifications page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05164553) it is an HM170 chipset. You might be able to find the chip on ebay (https://www.ebay.co.uk/p/6008316282) but I'm not sure how much I'd trust grey market parts from that kind of place and you would need very good BGA soldering skills.

Comment: Thank you. ……….